# update table in django from json

Tags: django

I have created a webpage with a table (bootstrap) I am reading a json file and displaying it in the table as follows

```
{% extends "blog/base.html"%}
{% block content%}
  <h1>Table Page</h1>
  <table class="table table-borderless table-dark">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Email</th>
        <th scope="col">Count</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for post in posts %}
        <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
        <td>{{post.Email}}</td>
        <td>{{post.Count}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>

{% endblock content%}
```

it works well, however the JSON file I am reading from keeps updating every 4-5 minutes and I need to constantly update the page, this is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json

with open('/home/usr134/tracker.json') as f:
    config=json.load(f)
def table_test(request):
    context = {'posts':config}
    return render(request,'blog/my_table.html',context)
```

I am new to django, I found plenty of ways to update but they use SQL, is there an easy way to do it ?

Note: the json  file gets updated using a python script if it helps

Comment: Do you know about cron job?

Comment: @MKPatel yes I know, do I have to restart server each time ?

Comment: Once you start your cron job, no needs to restart every time.

Comment: just run `python manage.py migrate`  in cron job and it will do it ?

Comment: Might be, it will work

Comment: @MKPatel no it doesn't

Comment: what do you mean by `constantly update the page`? Do you mean you need to reload the page to get the new data?

Comment: @Rajan once the server is running I am restarting it to fetch the new data, is there a better way ?

Comment: Do like i have answer below, things should be working then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you don't want to run `python manage.py runserver` to get the latest data from your file `tracker.json`.

Modify your `table_test` as below:

```py
def table_test(request):
    with open('/home/usr134/tracker.json') as f:
        config = json.load(f)
    context = {'posts': config}
    return render(request,'blog/my_table.html',context)
```

> If you don't wanted to reload the page you can make a ajax call to pool new data by returning json response from your view which will have similar code like the above. Or otherwise you can use socket as well.